# Redis Cache on 2 projects (Client Site & Admin Site)

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5, redis, azure-redis-cache

Hi can I use the same Cache service for two different laravel application? The scenario is I need to save users products in cache and once the user adds a certain product, the admin needs to validate it first, after the admin validated the product then it will be available on that users' account. In the admin **ProductValidationController** I need to forget all the users products in cache, so that once the users refresh the page his cache will be updated.

Comment: You should store this information in the database. Cache should be used only for storing data that you can re-create from other sources if it disappears.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to share cache on 2 different application just provide the same cache configuration in both applications.